# Get result based on checked services in form by joining two table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables, first is user table with user details and second is services table with service id stored into it.

**Table Users:**

```
 id    Name   mail             gender
-----------------------------------------
  1    John   john@gmail.com   Male 
  2    Mike   mike@gmail.com   Male
  3    Duke   duke@gmail.com   Male  
  4    Queen  queen@gmail.com  Female
```

**Table Services:**

```
 id   profile_email   service
 ----------------------------
 1    john@gmail.com    3   
 2    john@gmail.com    4    
 3    mike@gmail.com    3
 4    mike@gmail.com    5   
 5    queen@gmail.com   3
 6    queen@gmail.com   4
```

**Form Checkboxes:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="services[]" id="services1"  /> Service 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="services[]" id="services2"  /> Service 2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="services[]" id="services3"  /> Service 3
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="services[]" id="services4"  /> Service 4
<input type="checkbox" value="5" name="services[]" id="services5"  /> Service 5
```

Now my question is how can i join these two table to show filtered record based on checked service.

I am trying the below query but the problem is showing duplicate row. Please help me. Thank you so much in advance.m

```
$select  =  "SELECT a.*,  b.services FROM users a LEFT JOIN services AS b ON b.profile_email = a.mail ";

if(isset($_REQUEST['services']))
{
$services_search = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(', ', $_REQUEST['services']));
$select .= " AND b.services IN ($services_search)";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of your query you need to group the results as there is one -to- many relation between two tables

```
$select  =  "SELECT a.*,  b.services FROM users a LEFT JOIN services AS b 
ON a.mail  = b.profile_email";

if(isset($_REQUEST['services']))
{
$services_search = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(', ', $_REQUEST['services']));
$select .= " AND b.services IN ($services_search)";
}

$select .= " GROUP BY  a.mail";
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not entirely sure what you are going to do with those tables but you shouldnt store the same adress twice. Make a new table and save just the E-Mail adresses in there and then refer to them in your tables with a foreign key.

**Persons table**

```
id    name   mail_id   gender
-----------------------------------------
 1    John   1         Male 
 2    Mike   2         Male
 3    Duke   3         Male  
 4    Queen  4         Female
```

**Not sure what this is table**

```
id   mail_id         service
----------------------------
1    1               3   
2    1               4    
3    2               3
4    2               5   
5    4               3
6    4               4
```

**Adress table**

```
id    adress
----------------------
1     john@gmail.com
2     mike@gmail.com
3     duke@gmail.com
4     queen@gmail.com
```

No you can join the adress on wherever you use the foreign key of its id.
Something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, a.gender, b.adress
FROM persons as a
INNER JOIN adress as b on a.mail_id = b.id;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html